# require 'rubygems' for linux but not in windows. why? and can I fix this?

Tags: windows, ruby, linux, rubygems

I'm setting up a Linux development environment. After installing Ruby and RubyGems, I quickly found out that I need to `require 'rubygems'` in order to use gems, whereas I do not need to do this in Windows Vista. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Should I even be worrying about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to include `rubygems` by default (especially since Ruby 1.9 does that by default now).

Edit your `.bash_profile` or equivalent and add `export RUBYOPT=rubygems`

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your windows version is just doing this automatically.

Here's a thread on requiring rubygems:
http://www.rubyinside.com/why-using-require-rubygems-is-wrong-1478.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the one-click installer for Windows, I think it sets the RUBYOPTS environment variable to include the -rubygems switch.  You should be able to do the same thing in Linux.  There's more info here: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3